# Spoofing connection error in tests

Tags: php, phpunit, codeception

I'm currently trying to build an acceptance test for an API that pings other services to see if they are up. The endpoint gets headers and status codes for: domain1.com, domain2.com, and domain3.com. If one of those urls fail, then my endpoint will log the error. So what I'm looking to do is set up a test to call the endpoint and have one of the domains that I'm checking fail. So the basic test would look like:

```
public function it_should_return_failover(FunctionalTester $I)
{
    // change domain2.com to point to non-routable ip

    // then run the rest of my test...

}
```

is there any way that I can spoof one/any of the domains I'm pinging within the endpoint to a non-routable ip, or another way of getting a non-200 status code? This would be equivalent to changing the `hosts` file locally on your machine.

Comment: use php or Apache to return any header you want

Comment: Just inject a wrong URL to your application and expect a correct answer. If it works, your test is done.